# Let $W={\rm span}\{x^2-x^3,1+x^4\} \leqslant \mathbb{R}_4[x]$. Find a basis for $\mathbb{R}_4[x] / W$

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

**Exercise** Let $W=Span\{x^2-x^3,1+x^4\} \leqslant \mathbb{R}_4[x]$. Find a basis for $\mathbb{R}_4[x] / W$

So Let $W=Span\{x^2-x^3,1+x^4\} \leqslant \mathbb{R}_4[x]$.

Then $W = \{a_1(x^2-x^3) + a_2(1+x^4) \, \big| \, a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{R} \}$

It follows that

$$V / W = \Big\{ v+W \Big | v \in V \Big\}$$

$$V / W = \Big\{  v + \big\{a_1(x^2-x^3)+a_2(1+x^4) \, \big| \, a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\big\} \, \Big| \, v \in \mathbb{R}_4[x] \Big\}$$

---

There are a lot of moving pieces here and I struggle to figure out how to find bases for quotient groups in general. Am I allowed to just take my basis to be $\{v+W \big| v \in \mathbb{R}_4[x]\}$?

How does one form a basis for the set of cosets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V={\mathbb R}_4[x]$. Intuitively, $W=Span\{x^2-x^3,1+x^4\}$ means that in $V/W$, we have $x^2-x^3=0$ (equivalently, $x^2=x^3$) and $1+x^4=0$ (equivalently, $x^4=-1$).

Formally, I will write $\bar{P}$ for the equivalent class of $P$ mod $W$ (so $\bar{P}=P+W$). We then have $\bar{x^3}=\bar{x^2}$ and $\bar{x^4}=\bar{-1}=-\bar{1}$. Now, every element of $V$ can be written as $P=a+bx+cx^2+dx^4$ so

$$
\bar{P}=a\bar{1}+b\bar{x}+c\bar{x^2}+d\bar{x^4}=(a-d)\bar{1}+(c+d)\bar{x^2}
$$

so  $U=\{\bar{1},\bar{x^2}\}$ spans $V/W$. Since  $\dim(V/W)=\dim(V)-\dim(W)=4-2=2$, it is a basis.

---

**Other "method"** (more a rewriting of the previous one): Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ such that $V=W\oplus U$. Then $V/W$ is isomorphic to $U$ via the morphism $\varphi$ induced by the inclusion of $U$ into $V$ (that is $\varphi(P)=\bar{P}$).

It is clear that $U=Span\{1,x^2\}$ satisfies $V=W\oplus U$ ($\{1,x^2,x^2-x^3,1+x^4\}$ is a basis of $V$). Therefore, $\{\varphi(1), \varphi(x^2) \}$ is a basis of $V/W$.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just to clarify, I'm assuming $U = $ basis$(V/W),$ correct?

Comment: @SunRoad2: in the 1st method, $U$ is a basis of $V/W$. In the second method, $U=\{1,x^2\}$ is not a subset of $V/W$, but $\varphi(U)$ is a basis of $V/W$. I wanted to highlight that $V/W$ is isomorphic to any supplementary space to $W$ in $V$ (at least in finite dimension).

Comment: I see. Yes I was referring to the first case. Sorry